# Issue with printing to list (WPF) and editing information using C#

Tags: c#, list

I am currently a few weeks into a home A level computing course and have hit a bit of a hurdle, I will print the tasks I have but I am having an issue with 4,5 and 6, I am really stuck and can't seem to find any information on how I would go about this online.

1. Generate a random name: en-da-fu and el-kar-tuk could be names, so you could     make a name generator which sticks together three syllables from ‘word 
   banks’
2. Create the generic character class. Test to see if you can create multiple characters.
3. Create subclasses corresponding to different types of creature (B, E, W, D & K).
4. Make a program that randomly generates 10 of these creatures to add into a list.
5. Make a method in the character class that enables printing out of each character’s stats to the console.
6. Create a menu system that lets you add and delete characters and print out the list until you are happy with the team.
7. Create methods to let you edit any character’s stats and add this to your menu system
8. Create a way to save your team to a file and load it up again if needed

=======================================================================

## code so far, also have a listBox called partySelectionListBox

// This will search for and load the information in NameData.xml
        // and will also print the generic character class stats to a textbox.
        private void loadPlayerCharacterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists("NameData.xml"))
            { 
                XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NameSavingInformation));
                FileStream read = new FileStream("NameData.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                NameSavingInformation nameInfo = (NameSavingInformation)sr.Deserialize(read);
                playerNameTextBox.Text = nameInfo.GeneratedName;
            }

```
        BaseClassStats bClass = new BaseClassStats();
        bClass.health = 200;
        bClass.power = 50;
        bClass.specAttkPower = 200;
        bClass.speed = 50;

        string bClassStats = "Your current stats are :" + "\n \n" +
            "Health : " + bClass.health + "\n \n" +
            "Power : " + bClass.power + "\n \n" +
            "Special Attack" + "\n" + "Power : " + bClass.specAttkPower + "\n \n" +
            "Speed : " + bClass.speed;

        playerClassTextBox.Text = bClassStats;
    }

    // This will print 10 characters randomly from the array to a texbox.
    private void createPartyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] partyCharacters =
        {
            "Barbarian",
            "Elf",
            "Wizard",
            "Dragon",
            "Knight",
            "Cleric",
            "Theif",
            "Pyromancer",
            "Brute",
            "Unkindled"
        };

        Random r = new Random();
        int rSelect = r.Next(0, 9);

        int rs1 = rSelect;
        int rs2 = rSelect;
        int rs3 = rSelect;
        int rs4 = rSelect;
        int rs5 = rSelect;
        int rs6 = rSelect;
        int rs7 = rSelect;
        int rs8 = rSelect;
        int rs9 = rSelect;
        int rs10 = rSelect;

        // not sure how to set the listBox to = the result?
```

Comment: It would help if you gave some example code, to show what you have tried so far, or how the 'word banks' work etc

Comment: Nobody is going to do your homework for you.  You need to show some effort and the code that you have written, and then ask a specific question for a problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example let's suppose that your class is called `Character` and the constructor already exists as per points 2 and 3.

For point 4, you could instantiate a `List<Character>` and then use a loop, which iterates 10 times to fill it with 10 randomly generated characters, if you instantiate the List inside the loop it will be disposed of automatically upon each iteration finishing.

```
List<Character> characters = new List<Character>();
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++;)
{
    Character character = new Character();
    character.Generate(); //A method that would randomly generate a new character
    characters.Add(character);
}
```

Point 5, Though you have not added anything to state the actual contents of the class, it is worth assuming that there is in the "stats" a type, health and money (just an example)

This point can be done by adding a label or text box (not enabled) to the form and writing the stats to it, considering that there are multiple stats, it might be worth considering using a listBox too.

Finally for point 6 you should be using different form controls to make an intuitive interface, such as `+` and `-` symbols for improving and worsening stats, images that relate to the individual stats and even a limit to total stat points (20 total divided between 3 stats for example) In this there should be a button that calls the print method in the character class. This means that the method must be public!

Comment: Thankyou for your response Im not really sure how to post all my code but i have a class called baseClassStats that have 4 properties health, power, specAttkPower and speed and i set them manualy for each class, im assuming that i can highlight a character in a list then create an edit button that will take them to a seperate window, my issue comes with how to save them, i know how to save basically using Xml serializer but thats about it, should i post the code from this form or the form and the class files? sorry about this im quite new

Comment: There are a few ways you could save them, aside from just using the serialiser, you could write to a text file, which is of course not very secure and could allow for anyone to edit it, you could use a database and save the character stats to it as well.

Comment: hadnt thought about that! sorry for all the questions, really appreciate the help, i,ve posted my code in the question my other big issue would be making the box dynamic ( never used list boxes or check boxes before, as in editing the stats for each class then re printing them, would that mean selection the ones that arent checked to be re generated?) really sorry if this isnt very coherent just kind of hit a mind blank!!

Comment: If using a listBox, you can display all of them once, assume the listBox is called `statsBox`, you can use `statsBox.Add(val);` to add a string to the listBox, you can also set the font of the listBox to `courier new` which is a monospaced font, meaning that you can manually ensure that all columns are the same length if you wanted to display something along the lines of `Special Attack         10`. This allows you to pad without having misaligned columns. After populating it, if you want to repopulate with another print you can call the `statsBox.Clear();` method, which will remove all values

Comment: Thankyou so much for all your help Alfie will mark this as correct answer now thankyou for your time and help, have a lovely day

Comment: No problem, though one last suggestion if you have any more issues, ask your teacher, they'll really appreciate you asking them for help when you're stuck on their work!